# multiple recursive reference in same query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I know that Postgres doesn't support multiple recursive reference in same query. So I tried to re-write the query to get the same result but so far didn't have any luck.

can someone please help me how I can achieve this?

**Postgres Query:-(works fine in Db2 without 'recursive')**

```
 with recursive parent(level,pid,name,depth) 
    as ( select t1.level,t1.pid,t1.name,0 from table1 t1, table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.pid=t2.pid and t2.name=t3.name and t3.owner='me' 
    union all 
    select t11.level,t11.pid,t11.name,p.depth-1 from table1 t11, parent p where t11.pid = p.lev and p.depth<=0 
    union all 
    select t12.level,t12.pid,t12.name,p.depth+1 from table1 t12, parent p where t12.pid = p.pid and p.depth>=0)
select * from parent fetch first 5 rows only

**Error: recursive reference to query "parent" must not appear within its non-recursive term**
```

Table1
- - - - - - - - - - -
level | pid | name
..................... 
11    | 1    | X1
3     | 2    | X2
1     | 4    | X4
6     | 11   | X11
4     | 12   | X12

Table2
- - - - - - - - - - -
pid | server | name
..................... ...
12    | s1   | X12
4     | s11  | X4
1     | s1   | X1
2     | s    | X2

Table3
- - - - - - - 
 owner | name
.............. 
 me    | X1 
 1     | X4 
 me    | X2

**Expected Result**

LEV | ID | NAME | DEPTH 
..................... ...
 1   | 4  |   X4 |   0
 11  | 1  |  X1  |  -1
 6   | 11 |  X11 |  -2
 1   | 4  |   X4 |   2
 1   | 4  |   X4 |   3

Comment: What do you want to do? Please add some sample data and expected output....

Comment: @S-Man I have added sample data and output expected, please let me know if you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
with recursive parent(level,pid,name,depth) 
    as (
         with recursive innerparent(level,pid,name,depth) 
           as (   select t1.level,t1.pid,t1.name,0 from table1 t1, table2 t2,table3 t3 
                    where t1.pid=t2.pid and t2.name=t3.name and t3.owner='me' 
               union all 
                  select t11.level,t11.pid,t11.name,p.depth-1 from table1 t11, 
                    innerparent p where t11.pid = p.lev and p.depth<=0 ) select * from 
                    innerparent
               union all 
                  select t12.level,t12.pid,t12.name,p.depth+1 from table1 t12, parent p 
                    where  t12.pid = p.pid and p.depth>=0)
select * from parent fetch first 5 rows only
```